# Making a data frame using to lists of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have two lists of alphabets. List2 has some elements missing from List1.

ex: List1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f] List2 = [a,c,f]

List2 is the column of a dataframe df.

I want to create a new dataframe dfnew such that:

```py
if List2[i]== List1[i]:
    new_row=df1.loc[i]

elif List2[i]!=List1[i]:
     new_row=np.nan

new_row_df=pd.DataFrame(new_row)

df_new=pd.concat([df_new,new_row_df],ignore_index=True)
df_new=df_new.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

and then continue till List2 becomes equal to List1 that is the elements of the column of the new dataframe are the same as List1.

List1:  F,L,D,G,H
List2:  F,L,B,L,D,G,A,H,C

I have an existing dataframe only corresponding to List1. We only know the complete alphabetical sequence which is List2 but no dataframe corresponding to it.

df:

|  | ID | Val | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 122.58 | F |
| 1 | 4 | 123.11 | L |
| 2 | 5 | 120.54 | D |
| 3 | 6 | 108.57 | G |
| 4 | 8 | 119.83 | H |

Output:

|  | ID | Val | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 122.58 | F |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | **L** |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | **B** |
| 3 | 4 | 123.11 | L |
| 4 | 5 | 120.54 | D |
| 5 | 6 | 108.57 | G |
| 6 | 7 | 0 | **A** |
| 7 | 8 | 119.83 | H |
| 8 | 9 | 0 | **C** |

Answer (score 0):

Simply create 2 dataframes and merge them on the values like this:

```py
List1 = list('abcdef')
List2 = list('acf')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'List1': List1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'List2': List2})
df1.merge(df2, left_on='List1', right_on='List2', how='outer')
```

returns

```
    List1   List2
0   a   a
1   b   NaN
2   c   c
3   d   NaN
4   e   NaN
5   f   f
```

Comment: Thanks. I have created a pseudo example for my problem. Any suggestions on how to approach it? @MrE

Comment: same thing: merge the 2 on the NAME colum using 'outer' join.